# MAMP phpMyAdmin database dump import

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I completely removed Acquia Dev Desktop & XAMPP and installed MAMP.

Plain vanilla Drupal 8 that I downloaded from drupal.org works.

Now I want to import the database dump created by ADD, but keep getting an error message saying the file is too big. I believe the problem centers around php.ini. I can find no php.ini in the WAMP folder. I found php.ini-development & php.ini-production. I increased the parameters in both files relating to maximum file size upload, but they had no effect. I then copied php.ini-development & renamed it php.ini. I restarted the server, but it had no effect. Got any ideas as to how to fix this problem?

Parameters changed -
    max_execution_time = 30 to 1200

```
Changed post_max_size=8M to 128M
max_execution_time = 60 to 90000
upload_max_filesize=2M to 128M
```

Versions -

MAMP 3.2.0

```
    Apache 2.2.27
    Nginx 1.7.5
    MySQL 5.5.41
    PHP 5.3.23 & 5.4.1 & PHP 5.4.40 & 5.4.45 & 5.5.0 & 5.5.24 & 5.5.29 & 5.6.0 & 5.6.8 & 5.6.13 & 7.0.0
    OpenSSL 1.0.2e
    APC 3.1.13
    APCu 4.0.4 & 4.0.7
    eAccelerator 1.0
    XCache 3.0.4 & 3.1.0
    OPCache 7.0.4
    Python 2.7.6
    mod_wsgi 3.4.0
    Perl 5.16.1
    mod_perl 2.0.8
    phpMyAdmin 4.2.7
    SQLiteManager 1.2.4
    phpLiteAdmin 1.9.4.1
    Freetype 2.4.10
    curl 7.36.0
    libpng 1.5.18
    ImageMagick 6.8.9-1
    Imagick 3.1.2
    gd 2.1.0
    zlib 1.2.7
    libxml2 2.9.1
    gettext 0.18.1.1
    iconv 1.14
    mcrypt 2.5.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Thanks to help from ostraining.com, I found php.ini at C:\MAMP\conf\php7.0.0.

Note: There is more than one php folder inside mamp/conf. Click Preferences on the MAMP console then the php tab to find out which one is in use.